# Mongodb sorting by one column with multiple values

Tags: mongodb

I am using node.js Express, mongo-db database I'am stuck in following problem!!!

In database, post collection have one column named **"seen_by"** ,its type is array.
If user have seen that post , the "seen_by" array  would contain it's user_id.
Now I have to get data in post collection, list down user's unseen posts following seen posts.

Now My question is how to sort one cloumn by two diffrent values in mongodb

Example:

1. post_id :10, name: test, post_date :10/14/2020, Seen_by: Array, 0: 10,
2. post_id :11, name: test1, post_date :10/15/2020, Seen_by: Array, 0: 10,
3. post_id :15, name: tabf, post_date :09/14/2020, Seen_by: Array, 0: 1,
4. post_id :20, name: userTest, post_date :10/14/2020, Seen_by: Array, 0: 10

If now login user id Is 1 then Output should like this:
1)Post_id :10,....
2)post_id:11,....
3)post_id :20,...
4)post_id:15,...

How to get above response in Mongo-db ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate function.
First project one field to represent whether the use seen the article or not.
And then sorting, you can specify multiple fields in MongoDB sorting and order represent the sorting condition.

Here is the sample https://mongoplayground.net/p/PZDhKr33Qr-

Comment: can you  please tell me that What is "$project" ??

Comment: $project means to select the fields you want or set the addition field.  If you are not familiar with these commands, it would be better to see the document which is pretty clear. Also see how to user aggregation, it is super powerful https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/